# Не получается выполнить команду push origin master

Tags: git

После отправки команды ничего не происходит, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю.
Новичок при работе с git.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше вопрос оформить в виде текста, скопируйте из консоли в ставьте вместо фото, так ваш вопрос может помочь и другим людям, которые найдут его в поиске.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В директории с проектом

```
git add .
git commit -m "Name"
git push -u
```

Первая команда добавит все измененные файлы к коммиту.
Вторая - создаст комит с именем Name
Третья - продвинет ветку вперед на 1 комит в текущей ветке, в вашем случае master

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!

Comment: Пожалуйста, но всё же в знак благодарности подредактируйте вопрос для сообщества!